# Silverlight Datagrid - Getting The Data?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, datagrid

This may sound stupid....I've followed Scott Morrisons [Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/scmorris/archive/2008/10/14/silverlight-2-datagrid-is-released.aspx) and have implemented a silverlight datagrid and populated it with some data. My question now is, when I edit the datagrid and change some of the data, how do i then retrieve it back?! I guess what i'm trying to say is - does it get posted back somewhere!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Brad Abrams MIX09 tutorials located on his blog has ALL the answers I could have possibly ever wanted when starting out with such a powerful framework.
[Brad's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you bind your columns of your data grid to the properties, you should specify that the binding is a two-way binding.  This will update the back end data as the grid data is changed.

For a more thorough read, you should look at this [article](http://silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/databinding.aspx).